# Cordova android run/build Error - Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8

Tags: java, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap, android-build

I have built my cordova app and getting "Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8" error message.

Uninstalling all java and installing jdk 1.8 not solved my problem.

D:\xampp\htdocs\aware>cordova run android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Baha\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221
Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8

ScreenShots:
[image: Error message when cordova runs/builds android]

[image: JAVA_HOME ENV.]

[image: JDK setup]

[image: jdk folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have installed more than one Java (binaries) on your system. First of all, check this, by executing `where java` command in your `cmd.exe` (command line).

1. Most likely, you will see more than one `java.exe` installed, and if so, this may be the reason, despite installing new Java, your system still provides one more other version of it;
2. Even if you have set your `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable accordingly, there might be another `java.exe` available in your environment, either because of having some other Java binaries' **bin** folder added in the System variables' (under Environment Variables) `Path` variable, or because of having it at some other place, which is also available through any other environment variable (for instance: **System32** on Windows).

Check `where java` and see your `Path` environment variable under the System Variables.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I use windows powershell, I can build the app but, when I use IDE terminal I get an error.

Comment: Try to set the proper JDK for the IDE. Also, if my answer helped you, I would appreciate your upvote and marking this answer as an accepted one.

Comment: How can I set proper JDK for spesific IDE ?

Comment: If you're using IntelliJ (if I'm not mistaken), you would want to try: File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved partially, I have changed the path and try to build with vs code, it works, but phpstorm still not build my app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have realized that vs code uses Windows PowerShell and PhpStorm uses cmd. PowerShell can build the app but cmd can not.

Comment: I have changed PhpStorm terminal to Windows Power Shell but still same error :(

Comment: Can you post entire log of error? this one looks like Gradle version problem. From >=5.0 versions, there are some changes. Try to downgrade gradle if this is a problem as well.