# How can I set Cordova Emulator on Ionic?

Tags: android, variables, ionic-framework, frameworks, environment

I have a problem with Visual studio code (ionic project).
I know that there are a thousand of these questions but I didn't find a solution to my problem. When I run cordova emulate android, this is the exit code (obviously I did cordova add android before and it worked).

[After cordova emulate Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sonol.png)

But i'm confused cause i've already set my environment variables

[Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSTvh.png)

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1LT7.png)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cordova android run/build Error - Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257104/cordova-android-run-build-error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8)

Comment: Probably duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57257104/cordova-android-run-build-error-requirements-check-failed-for-jdk-1-8